# How to get programmatic access a site that requires login without password?

Tags: facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

Update: It appears that when there's no API or token, software seems to simply ask the user for their account credentials, and probably has to store this information.  I guess it can't be a huge security risk, since people are willing to share this information with apps like Mint:

[image]

So, my conclusion is that it is OK to ask users for credentials to other services if they can be secured safely and the user desires the service provided.

Many, many apps use others apps such as Facebook in order to get data from it, usually to verify the user is real and to get relevant profile data (e.g. a dating app would want age, gender, etc.).

When using such an app, I do not have to enter in my Facebook credentials.  The app simply opens up my Facebook/asks for permission to access it, and voila it's done.

There seems to be a lot of documentation for well known companies like Facebook, Twitter, and PayPal on how to do this.

But how is it done for an arbitrary website that requires a user/profile, e.g. this website: http://ae.com/web/index.jsp

Unsurprisingly, if I google for FaceBook, there's a heap of resources, and even it's own dedicated tag (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens).

However, if I start googling for American Eagle, e.g. "https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=american+eagle+access+token&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8", I get nothing relevant at all.

Comment: The system used for that kind of login via a 3rd party service is called [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). But a service/site has to _offer_ this feature for you to be able to use it to login and identify users on your own site. Just because American Eagle clothing has some kind of “login system”, does not necessarily mean they also offer an API that makes it possible for you to use it for your site. Whether or not they do, you should ask them (resp. consult their API documentation, if there is any.)

Comment: This is what I figured.  But surely developers find ways around this, even if they don't offer OAuth up front?

Comment: No, they don’t. You can not “use” anything that is not even implemented. That is an expectation that does not make any sense whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, that you want to enable facebook login for your website,

you still need to create a facebook app. then use the access tokens in your website. so when user clicks on login with facebook, the app will be asking for permissions and finally you will get the access token and you can use that in your site to log in.

Comment: I think my question may be confusing--I want to enable American Eagle clothing login for my website.  There is a lot of information on doing it for Facebook, so I would not ask that question.

Comment: May be they are not providing such a service